# Is it good practice to use span classes?

Tags: css, html

Is it wise / good practice to give the SPAN tag different classes within a DIV.  For example styling paragraphs of text that need a specific layout / position  colour etc... ?

Or are there better / more efficient ways?

Comment: That sounds pretty okay. If in doubt, show some code samples of what you are doing

Comment: and why not giving that specific paragraph the class?

Comment: As long as you use them for styling I guess it's fine. But semantically, instead of e.g. `<span class="abbrevitation">` you may want to use `<abbr>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have less HTML if you gave the paragraph itself the class, rather than wrapping the contents of a paragraph with a `span`, but it's perfectly possible to do what you've said. You can of course give multiple paragraphs the same class:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Or give the `div` a class and select the paragraphs using that.

HTML:

```
<div class="paragraphs">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.paragraph p { }
```

Or each one a different class giving you plenty of flexibility

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p class="paragraph1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p class="paragraph2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p class="paragraph3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

If you need to just highlight different bits of a single paragraph, then a `span` is acceptable, but don't forget to consider ready made tags like `strong` or `em`.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur</strong> adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, although the below initially answered my question, thanks for a really detailed answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
<p><span>my text goes here it is lovely text</span></p>
```

If so then you'd be better to simply add a class to the paragraph if possible:

```
<p class="myclass">my special text goes here</p>
```

In general there is nothing wrong with using span elements in the way you're talking about though.

Comment: @SteveHamber - No worries. I see you've accepted the other answer even though my answer was first and you said it answered your question. It would have been polite to accept my answer and simply 'upvote' the other answer. Good luck with your site anyway.

Comment: Ahh, sorry man.  I still haven't got the gist of how this site works yet.  I do apologise.  :(